# extracted data from sql for processing using python

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, numpy

I have saved out a data column as follows:

[[A,1], [B,5], [C,18]....]

i was hoping to group A,B,C as shown above into Category and 1,5,18 into Values/Series for updating of my powerpoint chart using python pptx.
Example:

| Category | Values |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 5 |

Is there any way i can do it? currently the above example is also extracted as strings so i believe i have to convert it to lists first?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse your strings (a list of lists) then create your dataframe from the real list:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

s = '[[A,1], [B,5], [C,18]]'

cols = ['Category', 'Values']
data = [row.split(',') for row in re.findall('\[([^]]+)\]', s[1:-1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
print(df)

# Output:
  Category Values
0        A      1
1        B      5
2        C     18
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `pandas.DataFrame` and pass in your data, unless I'm misunderstanding the question. Anyway, try:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d, columns = ['Category', 'Value'])
```

where d is your list of tuples.

Comment: The OP said the data are *"extracted as strings"*

Answer (score 0):

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

column = [["A",1],["B",5],["C",18]]

columnname=[]
columnvalue =[]
t = PrettyTable(['Category', 'Values'])

for data in column:
    columnname.append(data[0])
    columnvalue.append(data[1])
    t.add_row([data[0], data[1]])
    
print(t)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).